How to determine which Jordan form arise from the given matrix?
Matrices of the form
$$M=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & a & b\\
0 & 0 & c & d\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\qquad a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{C}
$$
will always have one of the two following Jordan forms
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\qquad\text{or}\qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
How can I tell from $a,b,c,d$ directly which form it will be without calculating the Jordan form (or other matrix decompositions)?
Almost always it will be form $B$, but why?

Ever heard of rank?

Oh right.......
